# Iterating source to calculate scripted field

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to calculate a scripted field where I need to iterate through the source. Assume I want to calculate if a person has children:

```
PUT /persons/person/1
{
}

PUT /persons/person/2
{
  "parent": 1
}
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
POST /persons/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "hasChildren": {
      "script": "_source['parent'].any { p -> p == doc['_id'] }"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the `HasChildren` property is always false. How I need to modify my script? Or is there a better / more performant way?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Is this parent/child relationship you are trying to emulate? And why do you have `hasChildren` in there? Have you checked out the [parent/child documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html) to see how that applies and what it's all about?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if the Parent-Child Relationship is the right approach. I have a list of person. The id of parent is stored on each person (if available). Now I simply want to figure out if the person is a parent. Following this issue looks like it is not supported: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11432 (By the way: my use case is a bit more complex but for the sake of simplicity I used such an easy scenario)